# md-autocomplete to blur itself after item is selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have an `md-autocomplete` which populates with addresses. When an address is selected the focus stays on the element. I would like the `md-autocomplete` to blur as soon as an address is selected by the user.

The reason is because when done on a mobile phone, the keyboard should hide automatically once the user has selected the address, whereas currently the keyboard stays displayed after address selection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question doesn't have many details, so I'll work off the "Basic Usage" Codepen available in the [1.1.4 docs](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.4/demo/autocomplete).

Basically you just listen for the `selected-item-changed`, and then trigger a `blur` event on the currently active DOM element.

[Here's the Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzyKoe). It works in desktop Chrome, but I'm not able to test if it will fix the keyboard problem on mobile.

I just changed the `selected-item-changed` handler as follows:

```
function selectedItemChange(item) {
  ///// Get the currently focused element
  var activeElement = document.activeElement;

  ///// Check that there actually was a focused element
  ///// and make sure a valid item was selected.
  if (activeElement && item) {
    activeElement.blur();
  }

  $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
}
```

Comment: just what I needed! Thanks a bunch.